# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.images.mysite.com/upload.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, ajax, dropzone.js

I am uploading files in mysubdomain `images.mysite.url` from application running on my site `www.mysite.com`.

For this I am using [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com) for AJAX file upload and PHP.
After selecting file it is showing message the `Server responded with 0 code.` at upload page and at console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.images.mysite.com/upload.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8085' is therefore not allowed access.

(for testing purpose, I first run on localhost same message after uploading to server)

On the server, my *upload.php*:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


$uploaddir = '/post/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Dropzone

```
$("i#dzopen").dropzone({
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        url: 'http://www.images.mysite.com/upload.php',
        previewsContainer: "#media-upload-previews",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        maxFiles: 10,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*,audio/*,video/*",
        init: function () {
            this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
                log("log " + responseText);
                       });                   
                }
            });
```

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: @mcklayin — No, they can't. JSONP only lets you make GET requests. It doesn't let you upload files!

Comment: You need to debug the problem. Use your developer tools. Look at the Network tab. Look at the request and response. Are they as you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code as is, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should have been sent.

You may have a server error, or something else that prevents the headers from being sent (headers already sent? content flushed? wrong URL?).

Look at your console and browser's developer tools network tab for errors and look at the headers.

After you fix whatever it is that prevented the headers form being sent, consider the following:

1. Dropzone sends a

   > Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, cache-control, content-type, x-requested-with

   header. You don't reply with `cache-control` accepted, so you will need to add it:

   ```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control");
   ```
2. You allow `uploadMultiple`, but only expect a single file.
3. The `paramName` that you specify in your dropzone config is different from the one that you use on the server (`"file"` vs `'userfile'`).
4. Your server does not return valid JSON, which the dropzone handler expects.

A contrived example that might get you started (don't use in production!):

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$uploaddir = '/post/';
$idx = "file";

$res = array("success" => true, "status" =>array());

if (isset($_FILES[$idx]) && is_array($_FILES[$idx])) {
    foreach ($_FILES[$idx]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        $status = array("success" => true);
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES[$idx]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES[$idx]["name"][$key];
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploaddir.$name)) {
                $status["message"] = "ok";
            } else {
                $res["success"] = false;
                $status["success"] = false;
                $status["error"] = error_get_last();
                $status["message"] = "internal server error";
            }
        } else {
            $res["success"] = false;
            $status["success"] = false;
            $status["error"] = $error;
            $status["message"] = "upload error";
        }
        $res["status"][] = $status;
    }
}

echo(json_encode($res));
```

## Edit:

Turns out there was a server issue. Apache's _mod_security_ had blocked the file uploads, but not normal POST or GET requests, and returned `406 Not Acceptable`.

Issuing

```sh
$ curl http://example.com/upload.php -X POST \
  -F "file[]=@/path/to/file" \
  -v
```

resulted in

```sh
> POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: images.sitename.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 719
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------755cbe89e26cbeb1
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
* Server nginx admin is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx admin
< Date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 08:06:59 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 380
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
```

(nginx serves as a reverse-proxy and Apache is behind it).
In such case, if you manage the server yourself, you can disable the problematic rule using *.htaccess*, or in other ways:

### Method 1 - completely disable mode_security for the file (less recommended)

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleEngine Off 
</IfModule>
```

### Method 2 - disable specific rule

```sh
$ cat /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep ModSecurity
```

(modify the path to point to your Apache error log), which should returns lines like this one:

```
[<date>] [error] [client <...>] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). <...> at REQUEST_FILENAME. [file <...>] [id "950004"] [msg <...>] <...>
```

Note the `[id "950004"]`.

It can be disabled via:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 950004 
</IfModule>
```

There are other, potentially better, ways of doing this.

Here is [a good reference for mod_security configuration](https://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mod_security).

Comment: I updated my `upload.php` with your content now it is showing `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://images.mysite.com/upload.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.smsiland.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 406.`

Comment: I want to upload multiple files simultaneously and want to return all its uploaded image path at success. I want to check it for 1 later with multiple

Comment: It may have something to do with nginx not accepting something in the request.

Comment: Are you using nginx as a reverse-proxy? Do you have Apache with mod_security switched on behind nginx?

Comment: I think there is nginx server I will asked my hosting provider.

Comment: I think it is related to mod_security. Check your Apache error log and see if any `ModSecurity` rules blocked the requests.

Comment: ok  by resolving this it will be able to upload images at my subdomain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92706/discussion-between-masteram-and-xrcwrn).